# FFC Connector and PCB

Tags: pcb, ffc

I’m very very new to this and just wanted to ask can PCB distortion be caused by a loose Flat flex cable in the connector?

Just trying to have a better idea if that’s possible.

Comment: Depends on the width (pin-count) (as well as other factors) of the connector and the distortion. But: Yes, PCB distortion can cause a FFC to get loose. If you see vibration as some sort of repeated distortion, for example, it becomes more obvious.

Comment: there is no reason to have the word `EDIT:` in your post ... it makes it messy ... just make the desired changes